# Convert and count beetwean 2 values

Tags: excel, microsoft-metro

I need help for Excel convert between 2 values, for example:

I have value number "27-30" I want to convert to "27,28,29,30"

And value character "S-XL" I want to convert to "S, M, L, XL"

Comment: What do you want the conversion to look like? Please provide an example of the data you have and the data you want in a  cell format

Comment: Example Cell A1:"27-30" and Cell B1:"27,28,29,30" (cell B1 value i want to convert)

Comment: @HengkyST are there only 2 conversions? or you have more of this kind?

Comment: @Gowtham what you mean ? I found solution use VBA but i dont understand how to get 2 value "27-30". Any solution ?

Comment: The number is pretty easy. You split the string by the delimiter "-" and then you loop from the lowest to the highest either concatenating the numbers or creating an array where you store them. The other one you would need an array that has {"S","M","L","XL"}, find the positions of both your value chars and loop between them outputting the matching values in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers `28,29 and so on` can be looped easily but for sizes like `S, M and L`, you need a lookup table.

`Column A` contains your sizes and `Column E`, the lookup for `non-numeric` sizes,

[image]

The code is here, the result on `Column B`,

```
Sub sizes()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, str As String, rownum As Long
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If IsNumeric(Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), "-") - 1)) Then
        str = Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), "-") - 1)
        For j = Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), "-") - 1) + 1 To _
                Mid(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), "-") + 1, 999)
            str = str & " , " & j
        Next j
        Cells(i, 2) = str
    Else
        rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), "-") - 1), Range("E:E"), 0)
        str = Cells(rownum, 5)
        rownum = rownum + 1
        Do Until (Cells(rownum, 5) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), "-") + 1, 999))
            str = str & " , " & Cells(rownum, 5)
            rownum = rownum + 1
        Loop
        str = str & " , " & Cells(rownum, 5)
        Cells(i, 2) = str
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```